# Is it possible to use Japid templates in scala project in play framework?

Tags: playframework

Japid templates are faster than scala templates in a scala project in play framework. So I want answer to my question. If the answer is yes then how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.
Check out the github wiki page "Using Japid Engine with Play Framework" at:

https://github.com/branaway/Japid/wiki/Japid-User-Guide

Comment: I don't see anything about Scala support in that documentation.